# Do I need to manage the Android asynchronous task lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Do I need to call cancel on an asyncTask in a fragment onDestroy event in case the asynchronous task hasn't finished yet when the user hits the back button and leaves the activity?

Do I need to also possibly check whether an existing instance of my asyncTask may still be running in case the asyncTask from the previous visit to the fragmentActivity is still running, hasn't finished or hasn't yet been cancelled?

Comment: If it's doing something you want it to stop doing when the user backs out / leaves the activity you should.

Comment: hey i got downvoted.... how come? :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to, but you should.

The reason is that it keeps running till it finishes, and starting on honeycomb, it even uses only one thread for all asyncTasks.

Anyway, asyncTask should be usually used for short time tasks, something like 1-10 seconds. It's not a rule, but it will help you achieve the reason why there is an asyncTask - to be able to run tasks in the background.

Here are some notes about [asyncTask from the API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) :

> "AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler
>   and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks
>   should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the
>   most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time,
>   it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and
>   FutureTask."

API of [execute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29):

> "Starting HONEYCOMB, tasks are back to being executed on a single
>   thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel
>   execution. If you truly want parallel execution, you can use the
>   executeOnExecutor(Executor, Params...) version of this method with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR; however, see commentary there for warnings on
>   its use."

If you wish to use asyncTask as a background task anyway, verify that there is only one single instance of it (and don't forget to cancel it when not needed), or use the next code which Google recommends to avoid:

```
public static <T> void runAsyncTaskInMultipleThreads(final AsyncTask<T,?,?> asyncTask,final T... params)
    {
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
      asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,params);
    else asyncTask.execute(params);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. interesting about the one single thread for all. i think cancelling the task on destroy seems to have alleviated some illegal state exceptions i was seeing when i was testing jumping through activities quickly & not letting async tasks finish.